# XML to MySQL Table Structure

Tags: mysql, xml

```
<product>
  <modelNumber></modelNumber>
  <categoryPath>
    <category>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
    </category>
    <category>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
    </category>
    <category>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
    </category>
    <category>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
    </category>
    <category>
      <id></id>
      <name></name>
    </category>
  </categoryPath>
</product>
```

This is my XML structure. Now, is it possible to create a MySQL table based on this structure? Or would I have to manipulate the XML data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be able to read the XML (if it had any values of course), but you would really need to explain the system the meaning of each value. For instance the  is a many-to-one relationship with a product, so the script has to know that it has to execute multiple inserts instead of trying to save it in one field.

I'm not 100% sure, but using this to create a structure automatically is not gonna happen unless you explain the system/script what to do.. it'd be faster to create the tables yourself. Since there are no details of a field either (primary key, unique fields, auto_increment fields, varchar/char/int, etc..)